# SVG animation with bootstrap is too small

Tags: svg

I am using inline svg to render my animation, but there seems to be a conflict with the bootstrap column codes. The animation is scaled to be way too small and I can only get the right size if I delete the column codes. That is, I need to remove col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4 from  but of course, the layout becomes corrupted then.
width: 100% in the css doesn't change the size.
width: 100vh and height: 100vh make the animation large enough but they also corrupt the layout. Please see attached image.[image]

Comment: I suppose the SVG element has a viewBox attribute that is way to big compared to the animated group. Please add the svg code to your question so that people at SO may help you correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks, enxaneta. I changed my viewBox from "0 0 100 100" to "0 0 40 40" like you suggested and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't see where I can mark the comment from enxaneta as the accepted answer.